# prevent php from automatically encoding '@' to '-'

Tags: encoding

I have this code using email addresses:

```
$a = "b@b.com"; 
$b = 'b%40b.com';
$c = urldecode($b);

echo ($a . ' ' . $c);
```

On the browser, both variables are displayed correctly: b@b.com

But if I use $a or $c on the server as username to read the user's account, I get errors because their values are: b& #8212;b.com (remove space).

If I use the debugger to check the value of $a immediately after the first line of code, then it shows that $a already has the "b& #8212;b.com" value. So there are no extra steps that could encode it.

Note that & #8212; is not the html code of the @ sign, but the code for a dash (-).

I tried str_replace(), but it does not work.

PHP Version 5.3.8

Update: It is a debugger bug, which they said they will fix. Thanx.

Comment: Show the code where you _"read the user's account"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I use the YII framework, so the code is simply: $usr1 = ar_usr1::model()->findByAttributes(array(
    'username' => $c,
   )); But the values of the variables are already changed immediately after they were assigned (long before reading the record).

Comment: Update: It is a debugger bug, which they said they will fix. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I find that it still works right inside the controller as well - although the debugger shows the value of the '@' as being '& #8212;'.

But it is still weird. Maybe it is just a debugger issue, because everything else looks fine. Thanx.

Update: It is a debugger bug, which they said they will fix. Thanx.